# Are there any movies based on Robert Heinlein's works?

Tags: movie, robert-a-heinlein

Is there any movie based on Robert Heinlein's work? If so, is there more than one?

Comment: It's funny, Dick got so many movies (many good) and Heinlein got so much crap. It is a sad day for a author when Starship Troopers is the best film adaptation of your work.

Comment: Can you imagine *Stranger in a Strange Land* or *The Moon is a Harsh Mistress* as movies? Just too much rich material, IMHO.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody's mentioned [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0374423/), which gives a more complete list than the answers so far (but gives no information as to how close each adaptation is).

Comment: The good news is that none of his very best work has yet been turned into an abysmal movie. Surprising that nobody's yet touched the juvenile novels, many of which seem very filmable.

Comment: user56 - i follow your sugestion and found that heinlein is in this writing credits in this movie i liked very much: Predestination (I) (2014)
Full Cast & Crew
Directed by 
Michael Spierig ... (as The Spierig Brothers) (directed by)
Peter Spierig ... (as The Spierig Brothers) (directed by) Writing Credits  
Michael Spierig ... (written by) (as The Spierig Brothers) &
Peter Spierig ... (written by) (as The Spierig Brothers)
 
<b>Robert A. Heinlein ... (based on the short story "All You Zombies" by)</b>

Answer (score 31):

[The Puppet Masters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111003/) is based on Heinlein's novel of the same name.

[Destination Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042393/) is based on one of his short stories.

There was also an episode of [Masters of Science Fiction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0772139/) based on a Heinlein story.  The story was [Jerry Was a Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0840894/).

Comment: Oh yeah... The Puppet Masters! Forgot about it. It follows the book fairly well, as I remember. I haven't seen the other two you mention. Will have to check them out.

Comment: are any of it ok?

Comment: @Jorge: I've watched the entire *Masters of Science Fiction* series (it's too short) and I thought all of the stories were done well.  I haven't seen the two movies.

Comment: I really liked the movie version of The Puppet Masters. It had some pretty good talent: Donald Sutherland, Richard Belzer, Keith David, etc.

Answer (score 27):

*Starship Troopers* was VERY loosely based on his book by the same title. That's the only one I know of. It's a terrible adaptation, as well.

Comment: I prefer to imagine that that movie never existed.

Comment: @Satanicpuppy - I actually felt the same way, but since I've watched it because it's been syndicated to TV so many times, I've actually grown to appreciate it.   The movie has Fallout style neo-40/50s culture that is great satire.  There are some hilariously gruesome deaths and actually pretty good special effects.  It probably has too much campy nudity for some viewers, but I should mention it has NPH in it, nuff said.

Comment: so, you know nothing for _stranger in a strange land_

Comment: i remember the trailer for that _starship troopers_ but i run away from it, didn't know it was based in an Heinlein work.

Comment: You did the right thing, but read the book if you haven't already. Most of the book is about him going through boot camp.

Comment: The movie was only really meant to be a fun little bug-hunting romp. The two direct-to-dvd sequels were truly bad.

Comment: So truly bad. But I'm with Mark....you get over it...in 15 yrs or so.

Comment: I felt like it would have been an OK movie (I liked the war propaganda vids and such) if they simply hadn't tried to claim it was Starship Troopers. Honestly, change a few names and nobody would have claimed it lifted from Heinleins book.

Comment: I was disappointed in the movie, but after re-reading the boo I realized that the book is 75% introspection, which is hard to create a good movie from. I was also disappointed that they didn't use the real Camp Arthur Currie / CFB Calgary for the movie. It had just been vacated when the movie was starting production, and was looking for renters, but that's a detail only a few niche fans would even have been aware of.

Answer (score 10):

The 2014 Australian film [*Predestination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)) is based on Heinlein's story [*'—All You Zombies—'*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies).

As discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/83288/4318), Heinlein's novel [*Red Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_(novel)) was adapted into an [animated mini-series](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216502/). You can see it [on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMeZjmQbj-0).

Answer (score 9):

There was also an animated miniseries made of Red Planet.

Answer (score 7):

There's also [Roughnecks: Starship Troopers Chronicles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roughnecks%3a_Starship_Troopers_Chronicles), and while not great is better than the Starship Troopers movie (though oddly enough, Wikipedia claims this show was based on both the original book & that awful movie).

Comment: Roughnecks was closer to the book in a lot of ways, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

It's got to be doubtful if it would ever get made, but there's a screenplay for Moon Is A Harsh Mistress [here](http://socalbrowncoats.com/?p=28)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure whether this counts, but there's a short video of "And He Built A Crooked House". It *was* on YouTube, but it's no longer available.

Comment: The video is broken.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen it but [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aFilms_based_on_the_works_of_Robert_A._Heinlein) also lists [The Brain Eaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brain_Eaters) from 1958. Heinlein sued for plagiarism, so it at least must be pretty close :)

Answer (score 4):

The low budget StarQuest: Beyond The Rising Moon, reedited and upgraded as Outerworld is adapted from Friday, though only various parts, names, actions and the planet Halcyon were used. Shot entirely in a D.C. warehouse, and using miniatures, it has the look of cheap, but it's quite good, and addictive. I recommend it as an um-(sort of)Friday.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge (And I've been an SF and film buff for decades) the listings above are all the Heinlein stuff which as been adapted.

You could nominally add "The Trouble With Tribbles" as being inspired by it. David Gerrold was purportedly unaware of any connection until long after the fact, but even he acked that the resemblance between Tribbles and RAH's "Flatcats" from The Rolling Stones is awfully close. RAH was contacted before its production by Paramount's legal dept. and signed off on the usage as acceptable to him.

I'd also note the similarity between Star Trek's [Operation: Annihilate!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation%3a_Annihilate!) with RAH's "The Puppet Masters".

I do disagree with the complaints about Starship Troopers. It's not a particularly close adaptation (Verhoeven really did NOT understand the culture RAH was writing about, as shown by the obviously Nazi-esque uniforms for the Intel Officers) but it's not an awful movie itself, and the book is remarkably didactic and Verhoeven did a fairly good job of getting a lot of that subtle material into the movie with the "internet 'Want to know more?'" elements -- which at the time was perceived as the future of the internet (i.e., "push" content vs "pull" content -- As usual, the commercial interests Got It Wrong. One reason why government-directed technology never works, and central-planning schemes always go awry. It's impossible to reliably predict the direction a billion people will trend things)

In other words, if you look at it as "based on" ST rather than an actual adaptation, then it's not awful.

Comment: "It's impossible to reliably predict the direction a billion people will trend things" - sure it's possible. I'm quite certain that whichever way it trends, it will involve Kardashians.

Comment: Didn't the Kardashians invade Bajor?

Answer (score 2):

## Stranger in a Strange Land

Has been picked up for a TV series for SyFy ([source](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/stranger-strange-land-tv-series-development/))

Not sure how well that's going to go, personally.

> The controversial elements, and true driving forces of the novel, are religion and sex, which Heinlein’s publisher at the time wanted him to cut out. But as the author noted to his literary agent, if religion and sex were removed from the text, what remained would be the equivalent of a “non-alcoholic martini.”

I know this strictly isn't a movie but thought that Heinlein fans might have a passing interest.