# Cartoon movie set on Mars, human kids with alien pet

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, mars

I've been trying to find a movie a saw when I was a kid. I don't remember the name, just a few details of the plot.

I remember it was set on Mars, there was a human colony there, like a dome city.

They had a conflict with an alien race that looked like furry humanoids.

The main characters were two kids, a boy and a girl. The girl had an alien pet, a little fur-ball animal.

Eventually they meet the "enemy" alien race and find out that their pet is an infant of that race.

Eventually the aliens help the humans to make the planet completeley habitable for humans, and in the end it is shown that the little pet has grown and is telling the story of the movie to some human kids.

Any idea what I'm talking about or did I make it up in my mind?

Comment: Welcome to SF Stack. Hopefully we can help answer your question.  Can you help us with some additional information that might be helpful in identifying this movie?  E.g. when were you "a kid". Was it relatively recently? Farther back?  Was the animation style anime or more US?  Did you watch it in English or another language?  Were you in the US at the time you watched it?  Any detail at all that you can remember can be helpful in trying to identify this. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: They did a *Total Recall* cartoon?!?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243911/teenager-on-mars-in-conflict-with-authority-learns-truth-of-martian-lifecycle (about the novel on which the miniseries is based)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The story which you describe sounds like Robert Heinlein's novel [*Red Planet*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_%28novel%29). I think you're thinking of the 1994 [animated miniseries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Planet_(miniseries)) adapted from the book.

The novel is set on Mars. The miniseries moves the story to a fictional planet called "New Aries". Two children, Jim and his sister Phillis, are the main characters of the series. In an early scene, Jim finds a furry native animal which can pull itself into a ball, project holograms, and repeat what it hears. He decides to keep it as a pet. Later, it's revealed that the creature is a juvenile form of an intelligent race living on the planet.

The miniseries has an [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0216502/). There's also [a video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMeZjmQbj-0) which claims to be the complete story.

Comment: I never knew there was an animated miniseries for Red Planet. I greatly enjoyed the book. Will be interesting to see how good the series is.

Comment: Yes! that's the one, I didn't know it was a mini series either. I dont' know why i had never found it before. Thank you so much.